# Difficulty getting option menu values

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Okay so I'm trying to make a diet planner that gives the user appropriate choices based on their diet. My issue is that I do not know how to pull from the option menu without using a class, something which right now I'd like to avoid.

```
viable_breakfasts = cursor.execute(
                'SELECT ID FROM Meals WHERE Type="Breakfast" AND Vegetarian=(?) AND '
                        'Vegan=(?) AND Nut_allergy=(?) And Lactose=(?) ',
                [vegetarian, vegan, nut_allergy, lactose])
breakfast = tkinter.StringVar
# selects all appropriate breakfasts from the database based on dietary needs
breakfast_selection = tkinter.OptionMenu(frame, breakfast, *viable_breakfasts)
breakfast_selection.configure(width=16)
breakfast_selection.pack(side='right')
meal_b_l = tkinter.Label(frame, text="Breakfast")
meal_b_l.pack(side='left')
```

This is the code in question that I need to alter, I'd like to take the value selected obviously by making a command in the option menu and assign it to another variable that can be used later.

Comment: It's a bit unclear on what exactly your problem is - which part are you having trouble figuring out? (And what have you tried doing?) - The [Python Wiki on Tkinter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter) has various links, maybe one of them contains information that can help you?

Comment: Well it's mostly I can't work out how, or find an example of how to take values from an option menu without using a class, if you could point me to any valid examples or provide me with one then it'd be a great help. Been stuck on this for days

Comment: In the link I posted in my previous comment there are some tutorials, such as this one: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/optionmenu.html which states that you can use the `.get()` method to retrieve the currently selected option (so that would be `breakfast_selection.get()`

Comment: Okay, thanks . I should be able to get a lot done now.